# Chakra Ui allowMultiple={false} not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, accordion, react-typescript, chakra-ui

How can I fix the issue where the Chakra UI Accordion in my React project doesn't close the previously open accordion when clicking on a new one, even though I have set the "allowMultiple" prop to false? Here's the code I am using:

```
export const ComponentName = ({Users}: any) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      Users.map((user: any) => {
        return (
          <Accordion
            key={user.imageUrl}
            className="accordion"
            allowToggle
            allowMultiple={false}
          >
            <AccordionItem>
              <AccordionButton className="accordionButton">
                <Text className="userName">{user.name}</Text>
                <Avatar src={user.img} />
              </AccordionButton>
              <AccordionPanel>
                {user.topics.map((topic: any) => {
                  return <Tag className="topic">{topic}</Tag>;
                })}
              </AccordionPanel>
            </AccordionItem>
          </Accordion>
        )
      })
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I tried using isOpen and isExpended but failed.

Answer (score 0):

official:

"If you set allowMultiple to true then the accordion will permit multiple items to be expanded at once."

Example link: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/accordion/usage#expand-multiple-items-at-once